# "argument "x" is missing, with no default" in openair package

Tags: r, openair

I want to calculate Cluster with the 'Openair' package. I read the trajectory data with:

```
traj_2010 <- read.csv("C:/Users/stieger/Trajektorien/traj_10.csv", header=TRUE)
traj_2010$date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(traj_2010$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "GMT"))
traj_2010$date2 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(traj_2010$date2, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", "GMT"))
```

Thus, I have trajectory data in form of:

```
head(traj_2010)
  receptor year month day hour hour.inc    lat    lon height pressure               date2       date
1        1   10     1   1    0        0 51.330 12.420  500.0    912.2 2010-01-01 00:00:00 2010-01-01
2        1    9    12  31   23       -1 51.350 12.523  464.1    915.2 2009-12-31 23:00:00 2010-01-01
3        1    9    12  31   22       -2 51.353 12.668  422.2    919.4 2009-12-31 22:00:00 2010-01-01
4        1    9    12  31   21       -3 51.329 12.840  380.9    922.0 2009-12-31 21:00:00 2010-01-01
5        1    9    12  31   20       -4 51.279 13.029  351.5    923.6 2009-12-31 20:00:00 2010-01-01
6        1    9    12  31   19       -5 51.218 13.240  335.1    924.2 2009-12-31 19:00:00 2010-01-01
```

I now use the command `trajCluster`:

```
cluster_2010<-trajCluster(traj_2010, method = "Angle", n.cluster = 5, col = c("red2", "blue", "green3", "purple", "black"), 
                         map.fill= FALSE, key=FALSE, main="2010", xlab="latitude", ylab="longitude", xlim=range(-35:35), ylim=range(35:70),
                         par.settings=list(axis.line=list(lwd=1.5), strip.border=list(lwd=2),
                                           fontsize=list(text=32)))
```

it runs some minutes but with the result:

```
|==============================================================================|100% ~0 s remaining     Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "x" is missing, with no default.
```

I am a little bit confused because in the past it worked without problems. Could somebody help me?

I am using the following packages:

```
library(openair)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
library(mapdata)
library(rworldmap)
library(dplyr)
```

Comment: loading plyr and dplyr packages a the same time can often run into issues, and the error looks like it comes from dplyr. I would start with that

Comment: Yes, in the internet I found that the error with summarise_impl is a problem with dplyr but in the first runs I didn't use dplyr package because usually I don't need this. Also when I remove the dplyr package, the same error occurs.

Comment: The package that you are using may load dplyr as a dependency. Try running the code without loading plyr

Comment: I now removed plyr and reshape2, as it uses plyr. The same error occurs.